# undefined local variable or method `post'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, posts

Here is my form for my comments _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([post, @comment]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write a comment!" %>
    </p>
    <br>
    <p> <%= f.submit %> </p>

<% end %>
```

and here is my posts form _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch do |f| %>
        <% if @post.errors.any? %>
          <div id="errors">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "Error") %> Prevent this post from posting</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>

                <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <p>
             <%= f.label :Edit_Post %><br>
             <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.submit  %>
        </p>

<% end %>
```

Here is my comments_controller.rb:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create 
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
       @comment.save
       redirect_to @posts
    end
    def destroy
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @posts = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
end
```

And here is my posts_controller.rb:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @posts = Post.all
    end
    def welcome
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @posts = Post.order("created_at desc").limit(4).offset(1)
        @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]
    end
    def posts
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) unless session[:user_id] == nil
        redirect_to login_path, notice: "You're not logged in" unless @user 
        @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]

    end
    def new 
        @post = Post.new
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
    def create 
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])        
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        @post.user_id = @signed_in_user

        if  @post.save 
            redirect_to dashboard_path 
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
    def show
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])

        @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]
    end
    def edit
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end 

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post, notice: "Your post has been updated!"
        end
    end
    def destroy
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @post.user_id = @signed_in_user

        @post.destroy

        redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private

    def load_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Having this issue. Any help will be appreciated. Here is the picture of the error I am having:

[image]

EDIT: Here is my log

```
Started GET "/posts/24" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-28 18:46:44 -0700
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"24"}
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 24]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "24"]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = ?  [["post_id", 24]]
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 451ms (Views: 412.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined local variable or method `post'
```

Your error message says it all. It tells you that, you don't have `post` defined in the corresponding controller action for your view. That's why you are getting that error.

So, you need to define `@post` (usually you use a instance variable in such cases) in the corresponding controller action i.e. `PostsController`'s `show` action. You actually need to define `@comment` as well as you don't have it in your controller action currently. So, update your `show` method like this:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @signed_in_user = session[:user_id]

    # you need to define @post and @comment
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    @comment = Comment.new(post: @post)
end
```

Then, you can use `@post` and `@comment` in your view, so your `comments/_form.html.erb` would look like this:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
. . . 
. . .
```

Comment: Alright, I see where you're going with this and it makes sense except I now have the following issue after making these changes.
Couldn't find Post with 'id'=

Comment: yeah, you may need to do some tweaks to get the `@post` and `@comment`, the idea is to have them defined properly in the controller's action method. How does `params` hash look like? can you do: `puts params.inspect` in your `show method`? You may have to do this: `@post = Post.find params[:id]`

Comment: Well after changing the @post to what you said I should I get this following error which is interesting.
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:post_id]
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/dashboard.html.erb

Comment: you changed `@post = Post.find params[:post_id]` to `@post = Post.find params[:id]` and after that you got this error? It does not make much sense  to me. Ok, keep it: `@post = Post.find params[:post_id]` but do a `puts params.inspect` inside the `show` method and let me see the output please.

Comment: Nothing pops up after I put the     puts params.inspect. The page loads like normal, Nothing else.

Comment: see in your log. it will print the `params` and what's inside. do: `puts params: #{params.inspect}` and check your rails log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90837/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-genobambino).

Answer (score 0):

Rails can pass instance variables from controllers to views, you should use `@post` replace `post` in `conmments/_form.html.erb`.

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment = @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: After doing this I get the following error
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty